# Having trouble with a GNUProlog file 'existence error'

Tags: prolog

Hi I have a gprolog file that I'm getting an error in.  I know what an existence error is, but cant find a solution.  In the part of the file in question I'm trying to set up proof trees.  Something is wrong in the last 3 lines after the `:-`

```
is_true(P,P):-fact P.
is_true(C,C<=ProofTreeA):-if A then C, is_true(A,ProofTreeA).
is_true(P1 and P2, ProofTree1 and ProofTree2):-(P1<=ProofTree1),(P2<=ProofTree2).
is_true(P1 or P2, ProofTree1):-(P1 or P2<=ProofTree1).
is_true(P1 or P2, ProofTree2):-(P1 or P2<=ProofTree2).
```

thanks for the help

Comment: The syntax looks very unusual. `fact`, `<=`, `if`, `then`, `and`, `or` would have to be defined as operators. You probably have some extra operators defined.

Comment: As @false points out, you've got custom operators going on here that you haven't mentioned. And your *something is wrong* is a bit vague. It's best to show error messages, etc, when posting problems. Is `<=` an operator you've defined? If not, then your `<=` should be `@=<` in Prolog if you are using it to compare terms. `<=` isn't a built-in operator in Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @false, you have syntax errors:

```
Quetzalcoatl$ cat <<.. > pl.pl
> is_true(P,P):-fact P.
> is_true(C,C<=ProofTreeA):-if A then C, is_true(A,ProofTreeA).
> is_true(P1 and P2, ProofTree1 and ProofTree2):-(P1<=ProofTree1),(P2<=ProofTree2).
> is_true(P1 or P2, ProofTree1):-(P1 or P2<=ProofTree1).
> is_true(P1 or P2, ProofTree2):-(P1 or P2<=ProofTree2).
> ..

Quetzalcoatl$ gprolog --init-goal "['pl.pl']"
compiling pl.pl for byte code...
pl.pl:1:20: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression
pl.pl:2:12: syntax error: , or ) expected
pl.pl:3:12: syntax error: , or ) expected
pl.pl:4:12: syntax error: , or ) expected
pl.pl:5:12: syntax error: , or ) expected
    5 error(s)
compilation failed
warning: command-line goal '[''pl.pl'']' failed
GNU Prolog 1.4.4 (64 bits)
Compiled Apr 23 2013, 17:26:17 with /opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Daniel Diaz
| ?-
```

Prolog is -kind of- declarative programing… try to think like that.

Here is a version with the gnu-prolog syntax ([gprolog manual](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html)). I don't understand your logic so you should verify.

```
Quetzalcoatl$ cat pl.pl 
%you should be aware of the signatures of your rules, e.g. is_true(+fact,?fact), is_true(?fact,?fact)
:-op(800,xfy, and).
:-op(801,xfy, or).
is_true(P,P):-nonvar(P),P. %P should be bounded to a fact (e.g. fact/1) existing in your knowledge base of facts
is_true(C,ProofTreeA):- A , C@=<ProofTreeA, is_true(A,ProofTreeA).  %A is ubounded ?
                                                                 %'if A then C' ---> 'A,C'     %assuming A is a fact in the knowledge base
is_true(and(P1, P2), and(ProofTree1 , ProofTree2)):-(P1@=<ProofTree1),(P2@=<ProofTree2). 
is_true(or(P1 , P2), ProofTree1):-P1 @=< ProofTree1 ; P2 @=< ProofTree1. 
%s_true(or(P1 , P2), ProofTree2):-(P1 or P2<=ProofTree2). this rule is the same than the above one

Quetzalcoatl$ gprolog --init-goal "['pl.pl']"
compiling pl.pl for byte code...
pl.pl compiled, 9 lines read - 1708 bytes written, 4 ms
GNU Prolog 1.4.4 (64 bits)
Compiled Apr 23 2013, 17:26:17 with /opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Daniel Diaz
| ?-
```